# How to generate classes with tool from XML to serialize in Silverlight?

Tags: xml, silverlight, serialization

What is the best way to generate classes from complex XML to deserialize in Silverlight?
In .NET u can use xsd.exe from Visual Studio.

u get something like this

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;

 /// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
// this is unknown in SILVERLIGHT [System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
//this is unknown in SILVERLIGHT [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
 [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="", IsNullable=false)]

public partial class Attest {

private AttestBet[] betField;

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Bet")]
public AttestBet[] Bet {
    get {
        return this.betField;
    }
    set {
        this.betField = value;
    }
}
}
```

but when i copy paste in Silverlight application i get Error for

```
// this is unknown in SILVERLIGHT [System.SerializableAttribute()]
//this is unknown in SILVERLIGHT [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
```

when i comment it, and use code without those 2 lines it kinda worked on a simple example. IS there any better tool to generate classes for use in Silverlight?

Comment: I used xsd in a Silverlight project.  I just did a quick search and replace in the generated code to remove all of the unsupported attributes.  It's annoying to have to do this manual step every time you change the schema, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You right nobody nobody really does that it easier simply parse the XML file. But you can use the code below when lets say you want to bind control directly to XML file and want to have nice serialize/desirealize. Typically I use this method only when dealing with large data that WCF cant handle (that is 50-600MB per call).

Create a new class named XmlNodeItem. The class represents a separate node from the XML file

```
public class XmlNodeItem
{
    [XmlAttribute( AttributeName = "Bet" )]
    public string Bet
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [XmlAttribute( AttributeName = "SomeOtherStuff" )]
    public string SomeOtherStuff
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Then create another class named XmlNodeItemList, which derives from ObservableCollection of XmlNodeItem.

```
[XmlRoot( ElementName = "Items" )]
public class XmlNodeItemList : ObservableCollection<XmlNodeItem>
{
    public void AddRange( IEnumerable<XmlNodeItem> range )
    {
        foreach ( XmlNodeItem node in range )
        {
            this.Add( node );
        }
    }
}
```

Then Retrieve your data

```
public DataClass: XmlNodeItemList 
{

var data =  AddRange( RetrieveData( File.Open( value, FileMode.Open ) ) );


 //Retrieve Data method

public XmlNodeItemList RetrieveData( Stream xmlStream )
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer( typeof( XmlNodeItemList ) );
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader( xmlStream );
        XmlNodeItemList list = ( XmlNodeItemList )serializer.Deserialize( reader );
        return list;
    }
}
```